# How to data mine google for most popular things out of a set?

Tags: data-mining, dataset, trend, internet

Let's say I want to get the list of the top 5000 most searched biomolecules on google - how would I approach such a problem?

One possible solution is to fetch the whole pubchem/pdb database and run searches on google, sorting them by popularity. But, given that there are more than 200 milion compounds, that would be a lot of search queries, and google would probably block the traffic due to suspected DDoS.

Is there any other way in which I am able to obtain such a list?

Note: It does not have to be from google. It can be most mentioned on pubmed/wikipedia... any measure of "popularity".